# Powershell - need to change only Subnet and GW for specific NIC

Tags: powershell, gateway, subnet

I have a situation where I need to change the Subnet and Gateway for about 170 servers but leave the IP address alone. It seems like this would be simple but the problem is that many of these servers have more than one interface on them so I have to be selective about which one is being changed.

Luckily I've named all my interfaces with a standard convention so I can select the interface I need, however since its Windows 2008r2 I'm using WMI.

Here is what my problem is: To collect information about the interface name I have to use NetConnectionID which is included in Win32_NetworkAdapter, but to actually make changes to the interface I have to use Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration which doesn't include the ability to select the interface based upon the name.

So what I am trying to do us is use the Index property which is in both collections to tie the information together. I first filter Win32_NetworkAdapter based upon the interface name, obtain the index value, and then attempt to select the correct interface from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration so that I can change the required subnet mask and gateway.

Below is my script; the very specific area that is causing the problem is the section where I try to get the Where{$*.Index -eq $Index} to work with a variable. If I set the statement to Where{$*.Index -eq 10) it works, but if I try to use the variable of $Index it fails.

Here is my code:

```
$index = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID='Swizzlan'" | Select-Object - Property Index
$NICs = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername . | where{$_.Index -eq $Index} 

Foreach($NIC in $NICs) { 
    $ip = ($NIC.IPAddress[0])
    $gateway = "192.168.1.1"
    $subnet = "255.255.252.0"
    $NIC.EnableStatic($ip, $subnet)
    $NIC.SetGateways($gateway) 
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? After hours and hours of searching has not turned up the solution to me and I know it has to be something simple.

Comment: That still doesn't work  here is what I have right now:

Answer (score 0):

Win32_NetworkAdapter value "DeviceID" is equivalent to Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration value "Index".

So, in your code try:

```
$deviceID = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID='Swizzlan'" | Select-Object - Property DeviceID
$NICs = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername . | where{$_.Index -eq $deviceID.DeviceID}
```

$deviceID.DeviceID is used because the first line returns a PSobject. Another way to do this would be as follows:

```
$Adapter = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID='Swizzlan'"
$NICs = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername . | where{$_.Index -eq $Adapter.DeviceID}
```

Comment: So the first statement does correctly collect the index value of 10, which is correct for my test server, but unfortunately the second statement when using the $deviceID still returns an empty set for $NICs and nothing changes. If I set it to the value of 10 it works fine. Ugh!

Comment: OK, found the problem. Should test my answers... $deviceID is a PSobject and not a string (because it is created using a select statement) Use $deviceID.DeviceID in you comparison statement. I will edit the answer.

Comment: this is what i have now but it still doesn't work:     
 
   $Adapter = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter "NetConnectionID='SwizzLan'" | Select-Object -Property Index
   
    $NICs = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName . | where{$_.Index -eq $Adapter.DeviceID}

Comment: In the first line you need to select DeviceID, or get rid of the select-object all together

Comment: okay I freely admit I suck at this - but I copied what you've written for the code right off the screen into ISE on the server and I don't get errors but it does not change the IP subnet or GW.

Comment: figured it out - I have to run ISE with Admin rights and then it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear. One way to get around having to run ISE as Administrator is to disable UAC if you can.